# Creating web page and app with Ionic 2

Tags: routes, ionic2

I am developing a web page with the Ionic 2 Framework, yo migh ask why and that is because is that I am building the app too. So I am doing just one coding.

The problem appears in the browser since the Ionic 2 framework does not use a router when i press back or forward on the browser is not working. So maybe some of you have a similar issue and has a clue how to make it work.

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to solve but if you're using `push()` method to change views when building your app, then you should be able to use forward and backwards within the browser as well.

In your `.ts` file something like this:

```
pushPage() {
   this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage);
}
```

Take a look at the `NavController` in the documentation for a more thorough overview: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#push

You may also want to take a look at Ionic2's `DeepLinker` to see if its also something you might be looking for.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/DeepLinker/

In your `app.module.ts` modify your imports to something like this:

```
imports: [
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
     links: [
      { component: HomePage, name: 'Home', segment: '' },
      { component: AboutUs, name: 'About', segment: 'about-us' } 
    ]
  })
 ]
```

Edit: After rereading the question, I modified the answer to directly address the forward and backwards problem.